# Why can't I post on my friend's Facebook Page even though "Who can post on your Page?" is set to "Everyone"? How to make it so followers can post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

My friend set up a Facebook Page and invited me to like it.  I've liked it, and I want to post on it, to support her non-profit.  But there is option for me to post, no post form or button that says add a post. I can comment on posts, but I can't make a new post.

She came over and we went into her page settings and she has "Who can post on your page?" set to "Everyone".

I tried two browsers and two computers, and my wife tried from her mobile phone (she also likes and follows the page) and same deal, we can't post. Only my friend (the page owner) can post.

I had her fill out a Facebook Support report but I thought I'd try asking here too.

I tried searching about this issue on Google Search and asked Google Bard and ChatGPT, but it all seems to come down to make sure the below setting is set to "everyone" and it is.

We even tried flipping from "everyone" to "me only" and then back to "everyone" but we still can't post.

[image: Screenshot showing "Who can post on your page?" is set to "Everyone"]